# Place product field value as variable in php

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a new field using ACF for woocommerce.
The field is called "position" and has default value 52.

Now I want this value as a php variable in a image generation script.

Inside one function I have:

```
$position = get_field('position');
```

and

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="position2" value="'.$position.'" id="position2" >';
```

At frontend I see that field "position2" is filled with the product field value 52. So that works!

In a different function in the same php file, I am trying to reuse this variable, and I can't get it to work. I need $position to represent '52' in below code.

```
function _create_image( $ax1, $ax2, $ax3 ) {
...
imagecopy($template, $sky, 148, $position, 0, 0, 660, 660);
...
}
```

If I do this, $position is an empty value in this function. I have tried global, and 'use $position', but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Just 1 possibility ... You may be calling the function _create_image() too easily in the processing. Try echoing a debug msg both within the _create_image() fnc, and also at the other prior test point that you did.

Comment: Could it be your variable $position is not defined as it’s contained as only defined in the previous function?